# #1054 - Unknown column 'tt.date' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql

I've googled all over the place and tried for hours, I give up... I can't for the life of me find a workaround for this problem... `#1054 - Unknown column 'bb.date' in 'where clause'`. I definitely need access to bb.date but I cannot access the alias "bb" in the nested LEFT JOIN but I need to access it. How to pass the alias into that scope?

```
SELECT
    bb.date,
    PP.max_sell_price_asofdate,
    i.item_id,
    bb.transaction_id
FROM items_transactions bb

LEFT JOIN items_transactions_details t
    ON bb.transaction_id = t.transaction_id

LEFT JOIN items i
    ON i.item_id = t.item_id

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        pp.item_id,
        MAX(pp.sell_price_asofdate) max_sell_price_asofdate
    FROM items_prices pp
    WHERE bb.date >= ss.sell_price_asofdate -- #1054 - Unknown column 'bb.date' in 'where clause'
    GROUP BY pp.item_id
) PP ON PP.item_id = i.item_id
```

Probably it is better if i provide more details of what i am trying to accomplish with the tables and some of their relevant fields... It seems my query is not correct even if i get access to the bb alias. Basically what i am trying to do is join all of the following tables and make sure that each of the transactions' items get the correct sell_price. So for example for transaction 611 which has a purchase of item_id 148 dated 2019-11-29 should be joined with the correct sell_price of 13 since the latest price history change for item_id 148 in table items_prices is dated 2019-11-28 which is sell_price 13. Currently it incorrectly joins all the prices for each item

table **items_transactions**

[image: items_transactions]

table **items_transactions_details**

[image: items_transactions_details]

table **items_prices**

[image: items_prices]

table **items**

[image: items]

Comment: Seems like a fair question - my only request would be, can you simplify this to a smaller example? Should be possible to come up with a relatively simple schema and [nested] query then you can present that without the other fields distracting us

Comment: I believe the actual question is how to restructure the query so you do not need to pass aliased field into nested sub-query deeper than 1 level.

Comment: can you try something like LEFT JOIN (select items_transactions.date,items_transactions.transaction_id from items_transactions  ) as tt ON t.transaction_id = tt.transaction_id

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: i removed all the distracting fields, this is the minimal requirement for the entire query to work... i tried rearranging it but still cannot find a way to get access to 'date'

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica thank you. i tried simplifying the query and updated the problem description. that's the simplest form i could come up with. i also included a stupid workaround but i'm pretty sure there must be a simpler solution

Comment: It's not a stupid workaround if its working.. maybe you meant "ugly" (because it's too long, too many joins) workaround

Comment: i tried rewriting it again and again for the entire day. and i keep running into the same scope problem, it's impossible. there must be a way to transfer the scope into there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use references to a outer table but not to a table that is in the same `from` clause that surrogate query. For example, you can move surrogate query to `SELECT` clause:

```sql
SELECT
    bb.date,
    i.item_id,
    bb.transaction_id,
    (
    SELECT
        MAX(pp.sell_price_asofdate) max_sell_price_asofdate
    FROM items_prices pp
    WHERE 
          bb.date >= pp.sell_price_asofdate 
          and pp.item_id = i.item_id
    GROUP BY pp.item_id
    ) max_sell_price_asofdate

FROM items_transactions bb

LEFT JOIN items_transactions_details t
    ON bb.transaction_id = t.transaction_id

LEFT JOIN items i
    ON i.item_id = t.item_id
```

Notice that a surrogate query is not so good for performance. Without surrogate query:

```sql
SELECT 
    A.date, A.item_id, A.transaction_id  ,
    MAX(B.sell_price_asofdate) as max_sell_price_asofdate
FROM
(
  SELECT
    bb.date,
    i.item_id,
    bb.transaction_id

  FROM items_transactions bb

  LEFT JOIN items_transactions_details t
    ON bb.transaction_id = t.transaction_id

  LEFT JOIN items i
    ON i.item_id = t.item_id
) A
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        pp.item_id,
        pp.sell_price_asofdate
    FROM items_prices pp
) B
ON 
   A.date >= B.sell_price_asofdate 
   and B.item_id = A.item_id
GROUP BY
    A.date, A.item_id, A.transaction_id
```

Comment: Yeheyyyy!!! Thank you very much!!!! Works perfectly!!! I really appreciate your time and big time help!

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie, you are welcome, next time, read about [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

And for displaying sell_price one could use:

```
     SELECT
        bb.date,
        i.item_id,
        bb.transaction_id,
        (
        SELECT 
            pp.sell_price
            FROM items_prices pp
            WHERE i.item_id = pp.item_id AND bb.date >= pp.sell_price_asofdate
            ORDER BY pp.sell_price_asofdate DESC, pp.row_id DESC
            LIMIT 1
        ) sell_price

    FROM items_transactions bb

    LEFT JOIN items_transactions_details t
        ON bb.transaction_id = t.transaction_id

    LEFT JOIN items i
        ON i.item_id = t.item_id
```